# JavaScript Пошаговое прохождение через массив с заменой местами элементов при соблюдении условий

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Задача - дается фраза, необходимо разбить ее на массив из отдельных слов, пройтись по массиву - за каждую итерацию нужно сравнить элементы массива между собой по длине, и если один длиннее другого - поменять их местами. Для начала не могу справиться с этим,буду благодарен если кто-нибудь подскажет, что не так.

```
var t = [];
var arr = ['1','22','333','4444','55555'];
var len = arr.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(arr[i].length<arr[(len -(len-i))].length){
        var temp = arr[i]; 
        var temp1 = arr[(len -(len-i))];
        t.splice(i,0,temp1);
        t.splice(arr[(len -(len-i))],1,temp)
    }
}
```

Должна быть сортировка и=примерно такая -

```
var arr = ['1','22','333','4444']
//первая итерация - т.к. 2 элемент длинне первого, то -
//arr[1].length>arr[0].length
arr = ['22','1']
//далее сравниваем уже 2 элемент с третьим -
//arr[1].length<arr[2].length
arr = ['333','1']
//потом третий с четвертым - 
//arr[2].length<arr[3].length
arr = ['4444','1']
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = ['1', 'I am a table!', '55555', '22', '', '4444', '333'];

// должно стать: ['I am a table!', '55555', '22', '1', '4444', '333', ''];

function customSort( arr ){
  // начиная со второго элемента
  for( var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    var curr = arr[i]; // сохранили текущий элемент
    var prev = arr[i-1]; // предыдущий элемент
    if( curr.length > prev.length ){
      arr[i-1] = curr;
      arr[i] = prev;      
      //Поменяли местами. Усё.
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log( customSort( arr ) );
```

Comment: Ошибка в формулировке: `любое положительное или отрицательное число`. То есть `0`, который символизирует равенство двух элементов, она возвращать не может?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ой, ага - исправил)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Благодарю за быстрый ответ, данные методы выполняют сортировку массива по возрастанию, к сожалению это мне не подходит,как ещё можно было бы данную задачу решить? Дело в том,что примерно должно работать так :

Comment: Я наверное просто некорректно выразил свои мысли,
или неправильно описал суть задачи,извиняюсь.Изменил описание вопроса.

Comment: @kelter переделал) Ага, сложно представить, где может пригодится такая сортировка)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME почему сложно представить?Может человек задачки решает в codesignal :)